# ASP.NET MVC Routing - "Blank" Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Can I set up a route that will get mapped from a root-level URL like this?

http://localhost:49658/

I'm using the VS2010 built-in web server.

Attempting to set up a route with a blank or a single-slash URL string doesn't work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "/",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

It results in the error "The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.". Thanks in advance!  My entire route definition is here:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "EditingTitles", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{startingLetter}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", startingLetter = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

Comment: Show us your other routes, I had a problem similar to above (and your notes on XSaint32's answer), my default route was resulting in a 404 unless i specified a controller/action and it was due to a bad named route eslewhere in my routes

Answer (score 10):

What are you trying to achieve here... a URL that looks like this? http://www.acme.com/ ? Because if you are, the default route will achieve that when none of the parameters are specified.

```
// Default Route:
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default", // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = String.Empty } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: You're right, that URL is what I'm trying to achieve.  I already have a route exactly like the one you specify . . . but I get an HTTP 404 ("the resource could not be found") error when I F5 my project and it hits the default URL, so it seemed like I had to somehow handle the "empty URL" case specifically.

Comment: Can you paste that route here?

Comment: Sounds like another specified route is bad, I had a similar problem and my default route was being overwritten and not handling the root url. Please post all of your routes in the question.

Comment: I recommend using Phil Haack's route debugger: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: Good point; I updated the question to include all my routes.  I'll check out the route debugger that was posted.  Thanks!

Comment: Since the "EditingTitles" route is added first to the routes collection and has default values, check to see if you have a controller named Admin with an action method, Index.

Answer (score 5):

***Using ASPNET MVC5:***
RouteConfig.cs file:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Homepage",
        url: "",
        defaults: new { controller = "Content", action = "Index" }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "foo",
        url: "bar",
        defaults: new { controller = "Content", action = "Index" }
    );
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{title}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Content", action = "Details", title = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Plus:
If you wishes to redirect your homepage to another route automatically, like "http://www.yoursite.com/" to "http://www.yoursite.com/bar", just use the method **RedirectToRoute()**:

```
public class ContentController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToRoute("foo");
        }
    }
```